# How can i replace folder name on rollover?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

By default my page loads categories with images from `/thumb-min/` folder, for example `95-IMG_6509.JPG` so it is:

```
/thumb-min/95-IMG_6509.JPG
```

in details page it loads:

```
/thumb-medium/95-IMG_6509.JPG
```

So on rollover i would like to change **/thumb-min/95-IMG_6509.JPG**  to **/thumb-medium/95-IMG_6509.JPG**

i would like to make `hover ZOOM IN effect` but dont know how to apply it to my site. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have provided the logic, As practice it helps you, On hover you can replace image source into your `thumb-medium` and updated that into your image source

```
var str = "/thumb-min/95-IMG_6509.JPG";
var res = str.replace("thumb-min","thumb-medium"); 
$('#your image Id').attr("src", res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<img src="/thumb-min/95-IMG_6509.JPG"
     data-src="/thumb-medium/95-IMG_6509.JPG" class="rollover" />
```

In the JavaScript, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".rollover").hover(function(){
    rollover = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", (this).data("src"));
    $(this).data("src", rollover);
  }, function(){
    rollover = $(this).data("src");
    $(this).data("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).attr("src", rollover);
  });
});
```

Or a simpler way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".rollover").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("thumb-min","thumb-medium"));
  }, function(){
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("thumb-medium","thumb-min"));
  });
});
```

For **Zoom In** effects, there are a lot of jQuery plugins. See this [**imgPreview**](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/), that works best for you!

Comment: simpler way got failed for me :) im givin a link http://expertonly.ru/index.php/katalog

Comment: You have an error in your JavaScript: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: php generating a link for image, thats a problem, i dont know really how it works :) but this is a code of image section dats why i cant add data-src donno what variable shows medium
        <?php if ($imgUrl = $this->getFirstImageUrl($row)): ?>
        <dt class="rollover">
          <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id='. $row->slug) ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_DETAIL') ?>"> 
         
   <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_DETAIL') ?>" /></a>
        </dt>
        <?php endif ?>

Comment: i thought without data-src Javascript will show something, but it just does not any work (

Comment: Can you add the code in the question and not as the comments?